# Documents tab Network error

Tags: error

Recently i upgraded to 5.61.4.
Everything works good except documents tab.
Every time i click on documents tab i got error
" Network Error Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again."

Any help please.
Thanks

Comment: Documents isn't part of an out-of-the-box civicrm set up. can you pls confirm what extension you are using?

Comment: I use  ( AuthX,  CiviGrant, CKEditor4, Data Processor, Expenses, Documents,  Displays relationships in the contact summary, Form Core, FlexMailer, SearchKit). Same extensio i use i old civiCRM installation. Thanks

Comment: Also, PHP Version 8.1.16

Comment: UPDATE: I switched to php 7.4 and works fine now. Apparently, extension Documents is not compatible with php 8.1

Comment: If there isn't already an Issue on the Documents extension repo but php 8 then please create one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the extension has php8 issue, I have submitted a [fix](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/documents/-/merge_requests/31/diffs) for it, If you apply the [patch](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/documents/-/merge_requests/31.patch) it should work for php8

Comment: Sorry, buy i do not have access to secure shell. Can i just edit file manualy?